# Asp.net Core 3.1 with SendGrid (with or without) Azure?

Tags: azure, sendgrid, asp.net-core-3.1

Can anyone help me clarify the benefit(s) (if any) of creating a SendGrid Account thru the Azure Portal as opposed to creating one thru SendGrid.com?

In other words, I’ve seen a few articles where they simply add the SendGrid Nuget Package, then create an account on SendGrid.com obtain an API Key and use it while creating a new `SendGridClient(apiKey);`

And then…I see a bunch of articles talking about having to create a SendGrid resource inside the Azure Portal. Once created, click Manage (which redirects you to the SendGrid.com website) to obtain an API Key and use it while creating a new `SendGridClient(apiKey);`

I agree that there are many ways to skin a cat, but I still don’t understand what’s the reason or benefit of creating a SendGrid Account resource in Azure (especially if all I really care about is an API key to be used within my SendGridClient).

What am I missing?

The only thing I can think of right now is if I plan on having a Logic App that will send emails, then I suppose I could use that SendGrid Account created thru Azure for that right?

Anyway...if anyone could help me understand why is there a need to create a SendGrid Account thru Azure that would be great!

Sincerely

Vince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is mainly the benefits you get from the Martket Place one. There is a [**`partnership with Microsoft`**](https://sendgrid.com/blog/sendgrid-in-the-cloud-with-microsoft/) which provides certain benefits to the end users. One of the highlight benefit is that,

> As part of the initial sign up, we are including a free package with
> 25,000 free emails each month.

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan, the partnership link helped me better understand.